# Angular 2: pipe items in ng-select

Tags: angular

is there any way, how to pipe items in **ng-select** component?

Les say, I have list of items, having 2 types of values, "valueA" and "valueB":

```
export class Item {
   valueA: string;
   valueB: string;
}
```

Then I have switch: "Show Values A" / "Show Values B".
Based of the value on the switch, in the dropdown I want see valuesA/valuesB.

I am using ng-select from https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Please provide plunker with the code you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would pipe here -- I would probably use an *ngIf or a single backing field that conditionally updates to drive the dropdown.

```
<my-dropdown [data]="conditionalBackingData"></my-dropdown>

...

showA ? conditionalBackingData = valueAList : conditionalBackingData = valueBList;
```